# CSS pressable button moves all list elements

Tags: css, button, margin

So I want to create pseudo-3d css3 button that uses box-shadow and margins so on click looks like it's pressed.

```
.button {
   margin: 0 0 5px 0;
   box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #000;
}

.button:active {
   margin: 5px 0 0 0;
   box-shadow: none;
}
```

And it works perfectly fine unless I try to use this code in a list such as:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#" class="button>Link</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="button>Link</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="button>Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Because in this scenario it moves all list links when I hover on one. Is there any way of fixing it? I'd rather stick to margins as position relative top bottom affects other elements on the page.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6tpR8/

Answer (score 11):

Add `vertical-align:top` to your .button class.

http://jsfiddle.net/6tpR8/1/

For an added effect add `transition: all .25s` to make it animated (Not fully supported but won't hurt in unsupported browsers).

http://jsfiddle.net/6tpR8/3/

Comment: helped me today..! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could float them:

```
ul li {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6tpR8/2/

Answer (score 0):

Just add a display.

Display : inline-block;

If that still doesnt fix it, you need to give it a width. So it actually knows how big it should be.

For IE you might need to add:
border:none;

Notice: box-shadow is different in almost all browsers